# Is there a way to modify the <span> tag produced from material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way I can modify the `<span>` tag that is generated by using the `Checkbox` component from the `material-ui` framework?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to change:

```
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-29 MuiIconButton-root-226 MuiSwitchBase-root-277 MuiCheckbox-root-271 Checkbox-root-265 MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary-276">
  <span class="MuiIconButton-label-231">
    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-168" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
      <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
    </svg>
    <input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-280" name="Chk" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
</span>
```

to (the change is in the first `<span>` tag)

```
<span class="MuiButtonBase-root-29 MuiIconButton-root-226 MuiSwitchBase-root-277 MuiCheckbox-root-271 Checkbox-root-265 MuiCheckbox-colorSecondary-276" tabindex=0>
  <span class="MuiIconButton-label-231">
    <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root-168" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
      <path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z"></path>
    </svg>
    <input class="MuiSwitchBase-input-280" name="Chk" type="checkbox" data-indeterminate="false" value="">
  </span>
  <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root-64"></span>
</span>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `Checkbox`](https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/) states that `"Any other properties supplied will be spread to the root element (native element)"`, so you can just give the component a prop `tabindex` with the value `0`:

```
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

function MyCheckbox() {
  return <Checkbox tabindex={0} />;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this actually adds `tabindex=0` to the native element `<input>` whereas I want to add it to the root `<span>` tag that wraps the `<input>` element

Comment: @Tim Ah, I see. I have bad news. [`CheckBox` uses `SwitchBase` internally](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/eaa00523987075ee31d1261df6b38f33962986f5/packages/material-ui/src/Checkbox/Checkbox.js#L56) that it gives all the extra props to, which in turn [extracts the `tabindex` prop and uses it for the input](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/eaa00523987075ee31d1261df6b38f33962986f5/packages/material-ui/src/internal/SwitchBase.js#L83-L104). You simply cannot get the tabindex on the `span`. Don't you want the `input` to be focused when tabbing though?

Comment: Ah thanks for looking into this. You're correct that I want the `input` to be focused when tabbing but for some strange reason, adding `tabindex=0` to my `input` doesn't actually do anything and it just gets skipped when I use tab navigation. However, playing around in the inspector, i found that adding `tabindex=0` inside the parent `<span>` tag solves this problem